# Does TPMS warning cause ABS and ESC codes in Chevrolet HHR?

Tags: chevrolet, abs, tire-pressure-monitoring-system, electronic-stability-control, hhr

My neighbor is elderly and I am assisting with her 2009 Chevrolet HHR, 2.2L non-panel. The cluster is showing warnings and messages for the Tire Pressure Monitoring System (TPMS), Antilock Brakes System (ABS) and Electronic Stability Control System (ESC).

My question is, does a TPMS DTC cause other systems to report failure, like ABS and ESC?

The reason I ask is, I know the tire pressures are good since I serviced them with air and put a gauge on them. I want to move onto her ABS and ESC problems. I want to look at the wheel speed sensors and their circuits with my scope, and possibly replace the wheel bearings/tone rings. But I don't want to chase a ghost caused by incorrect TPMS reporting.

Comment: Have you read the OBD error codes?

Comment: Is the car used often? Is the battery fully charged? Some cars are **very** sensitive to battery voltage (my car is one... will come up with lots of spurious faults if the voltage gets too low). Try clearing the codes and see which come back.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What Solar Mike said is a very good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. TPMS batteries are supposed to last up to ten years. When the battery fails, the warning light appears. My local tire retailer performed a free TMPS reading check on one of our vehicles and determined that it was not transmitting. After replacement (cheaper at tire retailer than at dealer), the TPMS warning light extinguished.

Consider to have the transmitters checked in a similar manner before replacing hardware. Narrow down / focus on the simpler aspect first.